# How to implement Share Extension that accepts text and URLs in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have built my app using Flutter, but I am not sure how can I implement Share Extension that accepts text and URLs in Flutter via Safari Browser into the Flutter Application. Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks for the help in advance:)

For example, when I go in Safari Browser and share some URL or text my app should be shown in the Share List and when I click the App it should open the Application with the Text or URL in a TextEditField.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about what you're trying to implement?

Comment: @baselsader Thanks for your response! I have updated my answer with more information regarding the same!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This package might help you: [receive_sharing_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent).

This code is from the example in the Getting Started section of the package:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:receive_sharing_intent/receive_sharing_intent.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  StreamSubscription _intentDataStreamSubscription;
  List<SharedMediaFile> _sharedFiles;
  String _sharedText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // For sharing images coming from outside the app while the app is in the memory
    _intentDataStreamSubscription =
        ReceiveSharingIntent.getMediaStream().listen((List<SharedMediaFile> value) {
      setState(() {
        print("Shared:" + (_sharedFiles?.map((f)=> f.path)?.join(",") ?? ""));
        _sharedFiles = value;
      });
    }, onError: (err) {
      print("getIntentDataStream error: $err");
    });

    // For sharing images coming from outside the app while the app is closed
    ReceiveSharingIntent.getInitialMedia().then((List<SharedMediaFile> value) {
      setState(() {
        _sharedFiles = value;
      });
    });

    // For sharing or opening urls/text coming from outside the app while the app is in the memory
    _intentDataStreamSubscription =
        ReceiveSharingIntent.getTextStream().listen((String value) {
      setState(() {
        _sharedText = value;
      });
    }, onError: (err) {
      print("getLinkStream error: $err");
    });

    // For sharing or opening urls/text coming from outside the app while the app is closed
    ReceiveSharingIntent.getInitialText().then((String value) {
      setState(() {
        _sharedText = value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _intentDataStreamSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const textStyleBold = const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Shared files:", style: textStyleBold),
              Text(_sharedFiles?.map((f)=> f.path)?.join(",") ?? ""),
              SizedBox(height: 100),
              Text("Shared urls/text:", style: textStyleBold),
              Text(_sharedText ?? "")
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi brother I was working with Momo payment gateway and i need to lauch deepLink that will open Momo app for payment, i achieved required functionality with intent for android but can you tell me how to do this with ios because ios don't have intent

Comment: This package is not being maintained anymore.